# For an extension of $\bigcap$ that outputs a set even for the empty set, how can we formulate and prove that the output exists uniquely for any input?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

When we construct math on set theory, we have two different ways to introduce the symbol $\bigcap$ for the intersection. Namely,

1. Introduce the symbol $\bigcap$ as a *partial* function symbol; do
   not define the output for the input $\emptyset$.
2. Introduce the symbol $\bigcap$ as a function symbol; set up a set of
   our choice as the output for the input $\emptyset$. Here, we take 41
   to be the output for $\emptyset$.

These are trade-offs with each other.
The first method has the disadvantage that there is no partial function symbol in the vocabulary of the first-order language.
On the other hand, the second method has the disadvantage that $\bigcap$ outputs a set that feels intuitively bullshit for $\emptyset$.

I decided to continue the construction of math in each of these ways.
Now, to introduce a new function symbol, we need to make sure that there is one, and just one output for any given input.
If we proceed on the basis of the first method, I could show formula
$$\forall \mathcal{X} (\mathcal{X} \neq \emptyset \rightarrow \exists ! I \forall x (x \in I \leftrightarrow \forall X (X \in \mathcal{X} \rightarrow x \in X)))$$
.
Thus, I could introduce $\bigcap$ as
$$\forall \mathcal{X} (\mathcal{X} \neq \emptyset \rightarrow \forall x (x \in \bigcap \mathcal{X} \leftrightarrow \forall X (X \in \mathcal{X} \rightarrow x \in X)))$$

If we choose the second method, however, I feel we need to show something like
$$\forall \mathcal{X} \exists ! I ((\mathcal{X} \neq \emptyset \rightarrow \forall x (x \in I \leftrightarrow \forall X (X \in \mathcal{X} \rightarrow x \in X))) \land (\mathcal{X} = \emptyset \rightarrow I = 41)) \ (\mathrm{formula} \ 1)$$

or

$$\forall \mathcal{X} ((\mathcal{X} \neq \emptyset \rightarrow \exists ! I \forall x (x \in I \leftrightarrow \forall X (X \in \mathcal{X} \rightarrow x \in X))) \land (\mathcal{X} = \emptyset \rightarrow \exists ! I \ I = 41)) \ (\mathrm{formula} \ 2)$$
to introduce $\bigcap$ as
$$\forall \mathcal{X} ((\mathcal{X} \neq \emptyset \rightarrow \forall x (x \in \bigcap \mathcal{X} \leftrightarrow \forall X (X \in \mathcal{X} \rightarrow x \in X))) \land (\mathcal{X} = \emptyset \rightarrow \bigcap \mathcal{X} = 41))$$
.
I first formulated as formula 1 and tried to show the existence, but I could not. Moreover, this formula seems intuitively to say something strange. It feels like this $I$ is a constant with a fixed value rather than a function whose value can change. However, the value is changing according to the condition.

I then formulated as formula 2. This represents only the "this case exists uniquely and that case exists uniquely" part of the argument of the form "there are only this case and that case, and this case exists uniquely and that case exists uniquely, so in the end it always exists uniquely", which does not seem to be a guarantee that the output always exists uniquely.

In the first place, is any of these the correct formula that we should show to check the unique existence of the output? And if it is, how can we prove it? We can use first-order logic and the ZFC axioms.
This question arose when I was reading [Kunen (2011)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/Set-Theory-Studies-Logic-Mathematical/dp/1848900503).

Comment: You came ***so close*** to finding [the question to the ultimate answer of life, the universe, and everything](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/245604-the-ultimate-answer-to-life-the-universe-and-everything-is-42)!

Comment: PS: We were able to prove formula 1, by dividing the situation into two cases depending on whether $\mathcal{X} = \emptyset$. This is therefore true. However, there still remains a sense that this is a strange statement.